# Page counter in Onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

So I was wondering If there was a way to put a page counter in Onsen,
by that I mean the little three dots that you at the bottom of your iphone when scrolling through pages
Im using something similar to this ->
http://codepen.io/negibouze/pen/jEvOYz

```
enter code here
```

So i want it that the three dots float at the bottom of my screen to indicate that the user can swipe left or right, and dots change as I scroll, so if Im on the second page, the second dot is bigger than the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `<ons-carousel>` as in the template, just add an id to the carousel and add an `postchange` event listener (on the initialization of the page where the carousel is) where you can change the sizes of the dots.

Also change the content of the `<ons-carousel-cover>` tag to a list containing images of dots or something similar.

Example Javascript:

```
<script>
    ons.bootstrap();

    document.addEventListener("init",function(event){

        if(event.target="#id_of_ons_page_containing_carousel"){

           $('#id_of_carousel').on("postchange", function(){   

               var index=document.querySelector('#id_of_carousel').getActiveIndex();
               $('#dot0').height(10);
               $('#dot1').height(10); 
               $('#dot2').height(10);
               $('#dot'+index).height(15); 

           });
        }
    });  
  </script>
```

In this case the `<ons-carousel-cover>` has the following content:

```
<ons-carousel-cover><div class="cover-label center">
        <ul>
            <li><div>
                <img id="dot0" height="15" src="White_dot.png" alt="" />
            </div></li>
            <li><div>
                <img id="dot1" height="10" src="White_dot.png" alt="" />
            </div></li>
            <li><div>
                <img id="dot2" height="10" src="White_dot.png" alt="" />
            </div></li>
       </ul>

</div></ons-carousel-cover>
```

In order for the dots to appear in one line add the following css:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;

}
ul li{
  display: inline;
  min-height: 40px;
}
ul li div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```